# I have Input text box which should take $ and £ currency symbols and warn if user types any other special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, currency

For instance, $1.50, 1.50, £4, 3.4 should be processed successfully. Where as just $ or % or # or !2.4 or &45 should given an alert ( special characters ) .

**Code: ( in JS )**

```
 validatePrice : function(price){
        var regexPattern = '^(\\$)\[0-9]+(\.\?[0-9]+)?$';
        if (document.asset_edit_frm.price.value.search(regexPattern)== -1){
            alert('Not a valid currency format ');
            document.asset_edit_frm.price.focus();
            return false;
        }else return true;
    }
```

Comment: I typically avoid storing the currency sign in my fields. You normally have to extract them if you plan on doing any math operations on the numbers later. I would, personally, store the currency type in a separate place. Just my $0.02

Comment: @Eonasdan - Could agree more, I've never seen the currency symbol stored next to the value in my experience.

Comment: @Eonasdan and m.edmondson: Yes i am stripping off all currency symbols in my java code and storing numbers in bigdecimal only but i would like to allow users to type in $ and  £ symbols in input box. So i have a JS which checks at the first step to allow only these symbols and warns for rest.

Comment: @the-first-two-guys so true, and if you are using more than the one currency, is it that hard to put a combo box to the left?

Comment: the point being that if you disallow currency symbols in the text field, you only have to check for valid numbers which can easily be done with a jquery plugin

Comment: **Define special characters!** Not ASCII?  Not ASCII letters?  Not uppercase ASCII letters? Not letters? Not uppercase? Not uppercase letters? Not‐Latin letters? Modifier letters? Ideographs? Non‐Common&Non‐Latin Numbers? Not ASCII digits? Not digits? Non‐ASCII digits? Symbols? Non‐currency symbols? Non‐ASCII symbols? Punctuation? Non‐ASCII punctuation? Non–sentence‐terminal punctuation? Unassigned code points? Format characters? Control characters? Nonspacing marks? Spacing or enclosing marks? Any whitespace at all? Horizontal whitespace? Vertical whitespace?

Comment: @Eonasdan That’s a lot of typing just for 2¢. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match the pattern you described.

```
^(?:\$|\u00A3)?[0-9]+(?:\.(?=[0-9]))?[0-9]*$
```

By the way, if this is straight JavaScript, define the regex as follows:

```
var regexPattern = /^(?:\$|\u00a3)?[0-9]+(?:\.(?=[0-9]))?[0-9]*$/;
```

Note the lack of `'`

Comment: It i tried but it's not working. It throws alert if i type in $34 or any value with currency symbol but it works fine with just numbers.

Comment: Currency symbols are `\p{Sc}` but for that you will need the nonstandard [XRegExp plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) because Javascript is so lame that it does not otherwise support Unicode (=code points **plus rules for handling them**), only ISO 10646 (=just code points without any rules).

Comment: changing var regexPattern = '^(?:\$|\u00A3)?[0-9]+(?:\.(?=[0-9]))?[0-9]*$'; and build.

Comment: @tchrist: i am aware of \p{Sc}, i am using this in my Java code to strip all currency format. But have issues with JS as u mentioned. I am not exactly understanding how to make it working.

Comment: @Paul Walls: Awesome it works as expected :) Suggest me any good reading materials to play with Regex. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html. Don't forget to tip your waiter. ;)

Answer (score 0):

checking for numbers can be done easily with this [jquery plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/)